# How to handle exception in oracle package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I have a oracle package consisting of many procedures.
e.g.

```
pkg(
proc 1
proc 2
proc 3
);
```

while executing the package proc 1 gets called first and within proc 1,proc 2 is called.
SO what if i face an exception in proc 2 then i want to rollback all the DML's done in proc 1.

Comment: you can use rollback with savepoint by which you can rollback to current transaction

Comment: please clear these: 1-**Proc1** calls **Proc2**? 2-**Proc2** does some DML?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything, Oracle will perform rollback for you. Just don't commit anywhere within those procedures - let the caller decide whether to commit or not, after everything is done.

Also, don't DDL as it'll implicitly commit everything that has been done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Littlefoot mentioned, please please have in consideration whatever IDE you are working with. There are some settings of auto-commit that I recommend to you that should be turn off. Otherwise, rollbacks won't help.